# How to connect entire network to VPN using RouterOS

Tags: router, vpn, pptp, bridge-router, mikrotik-routeros

What I have got :

Mikrotik stx 5hpndr 2

And the other devices on the network..

I used to share my vpn connection on my laptop to other devices so I needed to move it around the house now  ihave decided to connect the whole network to vpn so that there is no need to move my laptop again .

I have created a pptp client on the router and it has gotten connected successfully and I can see the local ip of vpn network but devices are not connect to the vpn network and they are connected to what they used to be

So how can I tunnel whole the network ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to create new network interface with bridged local ports and then bridge the pptp to this interface.